# Can I use WCF security without an SSL cert?

Tags: wcf, client-server, wcf-security

Ok, so here goes my situtation.

I am writing a multi site software which allows me to monitor process, memory, services etc on a Windows Server.

Each "site" will be a host as far as WCF is concerned. There may or may not be a central distrubition node, this will also be a host, but there will be an interface which reads data - this would connect to each "site" or the distribution node.

Right, so I want to secure this communication, encrypted. I don't wish to use any SSL certs, considering not every site/client will have SSL certs.

Can I do this? Using Message Security maybe? Only I haven't read a way to do this. I don't know if "Windows authentication" will suit this? Would it? A simple username and/or password solution would do. Much the same in the way the WebsitePanel team have used WSE to do it.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:

So I need to be more clear on this.

I do not wish to use SSL/certificates in anyway. Take it that I have no control over it. I could, if I really had to, encrypt each send of information in code manually, using AES etc, before it is sent, like PGP in emails, but I figured this is what Message Security is.

Such a simple task it is surprising to me that Microsoft and professional never thought to implement it. All data is sent pre-encypted and unless you have the coresponding encryption key you can;t read the data. Yes, I realise this is essentially the same as SSL etc.

Comment: "I don't wish to use any SSL certs, considering not every site/client will have SSL certs." Why can't you install SSL certs? If you mean signed by a public CA, then as long as you also control the clients could you not set up your own CA (e.g. your windows domain CA) and generate certs from that, and ensure your clients trust your root CA cert?

Comment: Take it that I don't control the sites and I have no control over SSL certs what so evre... I don't want to use them. All I want is an encrypted link.

Comment: Microsoft implemented message security but the implementation again uses certificates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encryption needs certificate to be really secure. WSE allowed user name and password but for message encryption it still required certificate - WCF does it in the same way.

You can build encryption layer without certificate but

- You will have to do it completely yourselves - you will have to implement custom channel which will do encryption and decryption.
- You will have to store encryption keys somewhere securely - that what certificates do normally. Once the key is compromised your security is gone. That is why certificates are used.

Windows authentication either again requires secured transport (basic http authentication) = HTTPS or both client and server must be in the same windows domain (if you communicate with your clients over internet that would require VPN).

Comment: WebsitePanel uses a "password" (stored in web.config) for its server components and "username" (from database) for the link between the portal and enterprise components. It however does not require a certificate or VPN for secure communication. I get what you mean about being "really" secure but I don't need it to be that secure... I just need it encrypted so its not plain text.

Comment: @Anthony: Then it probably used Username Authentication with Password Derived Keys - it requires implementation of UserNameToken Profile 1.1 which is not supported by WCF = you must implement it yourselves.

Comment: Is there another framework I can use to do the same job as WCF that allows me to do what I need that is current and in use?

Comment: As I know there is no other framework providing WS-* standards for .NET (except old WSE and it most probably didn't support this as well).